# Логическая реализация на Python

Tags: python

1. pacman -S ...

   - Manjaro Linux
   - Arch
   - ...
2. apt install...

   - Debian
   - Ububntu
   - ...

Я имею информацию о дистрибутиве(Manjaro Linux).

Надо получить информацию о том, в какой категории он находится(pacman -S).
Я не особо предстваляю как мне этот некий список-массив реализововать, без использования парядкового id(и с ним).
Я гуглил, не нашёл что бы помогло мне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, можно примерно так:

```
distr = \
{
'pacman -S': ['Manjaro Linux', 'Arch'],
'apt install...': ['Debian', 'Ububntu']
}

search_distr = 'Manjaro Linux'

for k,v in distr.items():
    if search_distr in v:
        print(f'{search_distr}: {k}')
```

Вывод:

```
Manjaro Linux: pacman -S
```

Comment: for k,v in distr.items():
    if search_distr in v:
        print(f'{search_distr}: {k}')

Поясните пожалуйста данный фрагмент) У меня ещё одна подобная задча появилась, с другими элементами и их количеством. Думаю если пойму эти 3 строки - вопрос ещё один оставлять не надо будет.

Comment: @Bogdan `.items()` выдаёт элементы словара в виде пар ключ-значение, таким образом цикл `for` перебирает из словаря сочетания ключ-значение, они находятся в переменных `k` и `v` соответственно. `if` проверяет, что искомая строка находится в списке значений `v`, соответствующих ключу `k`.

Comment: Огромное благодарство.